# Spring can't find CrudRepository beans when using ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create project structure that would allow me to add/remove modules by simply having them on classpath. With `@ComponentScan("com.companyname")` annotation in my Spring Application it detects and creates annotated components from modules. But I get errors when trying to autowire my CrudRepository anywhere:

```
Field repo in com.companyname.somemodule.services.SomeService required a bean of type 'com.companyname.somemodule.repos.SomeRepo' that could not be found.
```

So I thought that maybe it somehow can't create repos if they are defined in one of modules, so I wen't ahead and added test repo to my base SpringApplication and to my surprise I got:

```
Field repo in com.companyname.modularapp.TestService required a bean of type 'com.companyname.modularapp.TestRepo' that could not be found.
```

Then I just removed my `@ComponentScan` annotation and suddenly TestRepo worked as I intended, I was able to persist and read Test entities normally. So apparently ComponentScan somehow either screw up creation of CrudRepository, or it's later detection.

I define my repos like this:

```
@Entity
public class Test {
    @Id
    private long id;
}

public interface TestRepo extends CrudRepository<Test, Long>{}
```

I'm trying out Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 with this project but I doubt that's the cause.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can define package for Repositories scan by :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.companyname")
```

or in XML config

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.companyname"/>
```

Comment: This is just what I was missing! I did try it before, but did not know that I can pass package name to it. Thanks a bunch!  I actually got errors about Entities being unmanaged but I fixed it with `@EntityScan("com.companyname")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-boot you might as well drop the @ComponentScan annotation, as there is one already defined in the @SpringBootApplication annotation. Maybe there's a conflict of some sort between them, it's hard to tell without looking at the code.

Comment: Actually this whole mess happened because base app was not in "com.companyname" package but in "com.companyname.modularapp" while module was in "com.companyname.somemodule" so I did have to point ComponentScan one level higher.

Answer (score 0):

If you customizing package scans in your project, then probably you need to manually configure bean which requires path to scan, e.g. for JPA you can create your own bean of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` (you can find auto-configuration example here -
 `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactory` - class link from spring-boot 1.5.*).
But, if you do not require package scan customization, just put class annotated with @SpringBootApplication in project root, and pass it to spring::run method.